# Trying to reduce gaussian noise

Tags: python, signal-processing, gaussian, noise, telecommunication

I'm trying to minimize gaussian error by trying to average out my data set of 512x60000 into one having 512x1000. I'm doing this by averaging 60 columns row-wise but it's not working(index error- arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type). I'm doing it like this:-
north_data_pro = np.zeros((512,1000))

```
for row in north_data_fft:
    k=0
    while k < 1000:
        north_data_pro[row][k]=np.mean(north_data_fft[row][60*(k):60*(k+1)])
        k=k+1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this yourself e.g. by working with a much smaller dataset (a few rows/columns) and much smaller averaging (e.g. two rows?) to understand why your code isn’t working?

Comment: Yeah I had tried that and also went through some answers on stack overflow but couldn't find the problem. I'm also new to programming so I wasn't able to understand some part of the code of previous questioners. Now, the problem is solved though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At the `for` loop in your code, `row` is a list (or 1d array), *not* an index. So `north_data_pro[row]` does not make sense. An easy remedy is to replace the `for` loop with the following:

```py
for row_num in range(len(north_data_fft)):
    k=0
    while k < 1000:
        print(k)
        north_data_pro[row_num][k]=np.mean(north_data_fft[row_num][60*(k):60*(k+1)])
        k=k+1
```